# Split a string into an array

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I want to split a string to an array of sub-strings. The string is delimited by space, but space may appear inside the sub-strings too. And spliced strings must be of the same length.

Example:

```
"a b aab bb  aaa" -> "a b", "aab", "bb ", "aaa"
```

I have the following code:

```
var T = Regex.Split(S, @"(?<=\G.{4})").Select(x => x.Substring(0, 3));
```

But I need to parameterize this code, split by various length(3, 4, 5 or n) and I don't know how do this. Please help.

If impossible to parameterize Regex, fully linq version ok.

Comment: Are you going to automatically detect the length of the sub-strings?

Comment: No, length is stored in variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems rather easy with LINQ:

```
var source = "a b aab bb  aaa";

var results =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, source.Length / 4 + 1)
        .Select(n => source.Substring(n * 4, 3))
        .ToList();
```

Or using Microsoft's Reactive Framework's team's Interactive Extensions (NuGet "Ix-Main") and do this:

```
var results =
    source
        .Buffer(3, 4)
        .Select(x => new string(x.ToArray()))
        .ToList();
```

Both give you the output you require.

Comment: Thanks, this code works for me,

`var results = Enumerable
                .Range(0, (source.Length / (n + 1)) + 1)
                .Select(x => source.Substring(x * n, n - 1))
                .ToArray();`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same regex, but "parameterize" it by inserting the desired number into the string.

In C# 6.0, you can do it like this:

```
var n = 5;
var T = Regex.Split(S, $@"(?<=\G.{{{n}}})").Select(x => x.Substring(0, n-1));
```

Prior to that you could use `string.Format`:

```
var n = 5;
var regex = string.Format(@"(?<=\G.{{{0}}})", n);
var T = Regex.Split(S, regex).Select(x => x.Substring(0, n-1));
```

Comment: Life is easier with string interpolation.

Comment: Shouldn't you change the parameter of Substring function?

Comment: @RichardSchneider Yes, this is easily my most favorite addition to the language.

Comment: @Hamed Yes, I missed that part completely. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @RichardSchneider On the other hand, it is horrible if you want to localize interpolated strings, once you replaced `string.Format` with this neat `$` thing.

Comment: @UweKeim I strongly doubt that interpolated strings were intended for localization. It's great for things where the string does not get presented to end-users - e.g. diagnostics, SQL generation from metadata, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

A *lookbehind* `(?<=pattern)` matches a zero-length string. To split using spaces as delimiters, the match has to actually return a "" (the space has to be in the main pattern, outside the *lookbehind*).

Regex for length = 3: `@"(?<=\G.{3}) "` (note the trailing space)

**Code for length *n*:**

```
var n = 3;
var S = "a b aab bb  aaa";
var regex = @"(?<=\G.{" + n + @"}) ";
var T = Regex.Split(S, regex);
```

[Run this code online](http://rextester.com/VEBME54862)